# How to draw this diagram on LateX?

Tags: tikz-pgf, draw

I need to be able to write this out in LateX or in maple or in tikz.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! What have you done so far? Could you please add some working code([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that))?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hopefully this will give you enough information to get you started

```
\documentclass[tikz, border = 4pt]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \i in {1,...,5} {
    \foreach \j in {1,...,\i} {
      \draw (\i, \j) rectangle (\i + 1, \j + 1);
    }
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

These things are very reminiscent of Young tableaux, so why don't use them here?

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{young}
 \usepackage{tikz}
 \usetikzlibrary{calc}
 \newcommand{\tikznode}[2]{\tikz[remember picture,baseline=(#1.base),inner
 sep=0pt]{\node(#1)[inner sep=0pt]{#2};}}
 \begin{document}
 \[
 \begin{tabular}{l}
 \begin{Young}
  & & & & \cr
  & & & \cr
  ~& ~& \tikznode{13}{~} \cr
  ~& \tikznode{12}{~}\cr
  \tikznode{11}{~} \cr
 \end{Young}\\[1cm]
 \begin{Young}
  \tikznode{21}{~} &  \tikznode{22}{~}& \tikznode{23}{~} \cr
   & & \cr
  \tikznode{24}{~} & \tikznode{25}{~}\cr
 \end{Young}\\[1cm]
 \begin{Young}
  \tikznode{31}{~} &  \tikznode{32}{~}\cr
  \tikznode{33}{~}\cr
 \end{Young}\\[1cm]
 \begin{Young}
  \tikznode{41}{~}\cr
 \end{Young}
 \end{tabular}
 \]
 \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
 \foreach \X/\Y in {11/21,12/22,13/23,24/31,25/32,33/41}
 \draw[thick,-latex] ($(\X.south)-(0,2pt)$)--($(\Y.north)+(0,8pt)$);
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Forget `tikz`.  Stack it!  Here, `\sq` for a square, `\vl` for a vertical line segment, and `\ah` for a downward pointing arrowhead.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,amssymb}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\newcommand\sq{\framebox(10,10){}\kern\fboxrule}
\newcommand\vl{\rule{0pt}{10pt}\makebox[\dimexpr10pt+\fboxrule]{%
  \smash{\rule[0\fboxrule]{\fboxrule}{\dimexpr10pt+\fboxrule}}}}
\newcommand\ah{\smash{\makebox[\dimexpr10pt+\fboxrule]{\raisebox{3pt}{%
  \scalebox{.5}[-.5]{$\blacktriangle$}}}}}
\def\stackalignment{l}
\setstackgap{S}{\fboxrule}
\begin{document}
\Shortunderstack{\sq\sq\sq\sq\sq\\\sq\sq\sq\sq\\\sq\sq\sq\\\sq\sq\vl\\%
  \sq\vl\vl\\\vl\vl\vl\\\ah\ah\ah\\\sq\sq\sq\\\sq\sq\sq\\\sq\sq\\\vl\vl\\%
  \vl\vl\\\ah\ah\\\sq\sq\\\sq\\\vl\\\ah\\\sq}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If one wanted a version where the grid size and arrowhead size could be conveniently changed, see definitions `\gs` and `\as` in the MWE below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,amssymb}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\newcommand\gs{10}% GRID SIZE (pts)
\newcommand\as{.5}% ARROW SCALE
\newcommand\sq{\framebox(\gs,\gs){}\kern\fboxrule}
\newcommand\vl{\rule{0pt}{\gs pt}\makebox[\dimexpr\gs pt+\fboxrule]{%
  \smash{\rule[0\fboxrule]{\fboxrule}{\dimexpr\gs pt+\fboxrule}}}}
\newcommand\ah{\smash{\makebox[\dimexpr\gs pt+\fboxrule]{%
  \scalebox{\as}[-\as]{\raisebox{-1.3ex}{$\blacktriangle$}}}}}
\def\stackalignment{l}
\setstackgap{S}{\fboxrule}
\begin{document}
\Shortunderstack{\sq\sq\sq\sq\sq\\\sq\sq\sq\sq\\\sq\sq\sq\\\sq\sq\vl\\%
  \sq\vl\vl\\\vl\vl\vl\\\ah\ah\ah\\\sq\sq\sq\\\sq\sq\sq\\\sq\sq\\\vl\vl\\%
  \vl\vl\\\ah\ah\\\sq\sq\\\sq\\\vl\\\ah\\\sq}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Andrea You are welcome.  I've added an additional version that makes it easy to alter the grid and arrowhead size.