# How can I draw this Young tableau with LaTeX?

Tags: color, draw, technical-drawing, tikz-graphdrawing, ytableau

How can I draw this picture by latex?
[image]

Comment: Maybe starting from here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/429386/how-can-i-draw-these-young-tableaux-type-diagrams, reading a bit of the Ti*k*Z manual (at least follow the first tutorial), and then try something. When you get stuck, post a what you have ans somebody will help.

Comment: Thank you Rmano, Could you let me know how to color the boxes? Thank you!!

Comment: This figure can be build using a tabular.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have.  See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.