# How to draw a Young tableau with some grid lines disappearing

Tags: tikz-pgf, ytableau

I would like to inquire about creating a tableau that resembles the right figure depicted below. (I would prefer the right one, but the left one is also acceptable.)

[image]

I am unsure of how to eliminate some of the grid lines. I attempted the fifth diagram from the task provided below, but I am finding it challenging to construct the left part of my diagram.

[How can I draw these Young tableaux type diagrams?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/429386/how-can-i-draw-these-young-tableaux-type-diagrams)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please show what you tried so far. This site is not meant as a free coding service, so it is always very appreciated to show some efforts when asking for help. Also, this will improve the quality of potential answers.

Comment: For the package and its manual mentioned, see here: https://ctan.org/pkg/ytableau

Comment: I don't know the package, but it seems that is does not straight-forwardly allow for removing the inner borders. This is probably also why the linked answer contains a Ti*k*Z solution for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would not use the `ytableau` package since I am unsure whether it is possible to remove inner borders with it. Also, you want to place some labels inside the colored areas which might also be a bit tricky to achieve with the `ytableau` package. Rather, you can simply draw this using Ti*k*Z, for example like this:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt, tikz]{standalone}

\tikzset{
    cell/.style={
        anchor=south west,
        draw,
        minimum size=1cm,
    },
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

    \node[cell] at (0,0) {1};
    \node[cell] at (0,1) {2};
    \node[cell, minimum height=3cm] at (0,2) {$\vdots$};
    \node[cell] at (0,5) {$k$};
    \node[cell, minimum height=3cm] at (0,6) {$\vdots$};
    \node[cell] at (0,9) {$n$};
    
    \node[cell] at (3,2) {$a$};
    \draw[fill=cyan!50] (1,0) |- (3,3) |- (6,2) |- cycle;
    \node[cell, draw=none] at (2.5,0.5) {first part};
    
    \draw (1,3) |- (6,6) |- (4,2) |- cycle;
    \node[cell, draw=none] at (2.5,4) {second part};
    
    \draw[fill=yellow!50] (1,6) rectangle (6,10);
    \node[cell, draw=none] at (2.5,7.5) {third part};

\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}

    \node[cell] at (0,0) {1};
    \node[cell] at (0,1) {2};
    \node[cell, minimum height=3cm] at (0,2) {$\vdots$};
    \node[cell] at (0,5) {$k$};
    \node[cell, minimum height=3cm] at (0,6) {$\vdots$};
    \node[cell] at (0,9) {$n$};
    
    \node[cell] at (3,2) {$a$};
    \draw[fill=cyan!50] (1,0) |- (3,3) |- (6,2) |- cycle;
    \node[cell, draw=none] at (2.5,0.5) {first part};
    
    \draw (1,3) |- (6,6) |- (7,5) |- (5,4) |- (4,2) |- cycle;
    \node[cell, draw=none] at (2.5,4) {second part};
    
    \draw[fill=yellow!50] (1,6) |- (10,10) |- (8,9) |- (9,8) |- (7,7) |- cycle;
    \node[cell, draw=none] at (2.5,7.5) {third part};
    
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: It looks prefect! Thank you so much!